# Does jQuery's preventDefault() work for form's submit events?

Tags: jquery

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/WebApp/forgotpassword" id="forgot-password">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn">
</form>
```

with the following jQuery 1.7.2 code:

```
$('form#forgot-password').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.debug('Form submit');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Sure enough, I click on the Submit button, and then "Form submit" is printed in the console. However, the browser (Firefox in my case) still redirects to the JSON returned by the service at /WebApp/forgotpassword.

I haven't seen any other questions that seem to indicate that jQuery is broken, so I assume I'm using it wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, `e.preventDefault()` does work for submit events. Your code should work as-is. Ensure no errors are happening before `event.preventDefault();` is used.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the answers. They were exactly right. The problem was a nice example of technical debt:

Someone on a distant part of the system bound directly to the click events of all buttons, did some manual JS form validations, and then submitted the parent form manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes preventDefault will stop the event, you might also want to call stopPropagation as well.

Comment: You can also use `stopImmediatePropagation` if you don't want any of the other handlers to be executed. http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/